# org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException:PreparedStatementCallback; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException:

Tags: java, sql, database, spring, db2

I get a

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException. 

SQL state [51002]; error code [-805]; DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-805, SQLSTATE=51002, SQLERRMC=NULLID.SYSLH203 0X5359534C564C3031, DRIVER=3.65.102; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-805, SQLSTATE=51002, SQLERRMC=NULLID.SYSLH203 0X5359534C564C3031, DRIVER=3.65.102
```

for the following sql:

```
SELECT REF_TBL_ENTY_KEY, LTRIM(RTRIM(REF_TBL_ID)) AS REF_TBL_ID, LTRIM(RTRIM(COMP_ID1)) AS COMP_ID1, LTRIM(RTRIM(LOW_VAL1)) AS LOW_VAL1, LTRIM(RTRIM(HI_VAL1)) AS HI_VAL1, LTRIM(RTRIM(COMP_ID2)) AS COMP_ID2, LTRIM(RTRIM(LOW_VAL2)) AS LOW_VAL2, LTRIM(RTRIM(HI_VAL2)) AS HI_VAL2, LTRIM(RTRIM(COMP_ID3)) AS COMP_ID3, LTRIM(RTRIM(LOW_VAL3)) AS LOW_VAL3, LTRIM(RTRIM(HI_VAL3)) AS HI_VAL3, LTRIM(RTRIM(COMP_ID4)) AS COMP_ID4, LTRIM(RTRIM(LOW_VAL4)) AS LOW_VAL4, LTRIM(RTRIM(HI_VAL4)) AS HI_VAL4, LTRIM(RTRIM(COMP_ID5)) AS COMP_ID5, LTRIM(RTRIM(LOW_VAL5)) AS LOW_VAL5, LTRIM(RTRIM(HI_VAL5)) AS HI_VAL5, LTRIM(RTRIM(COMP_ID6)) AS COMP_ID6, LTRIM(RTRIM(LOW_VAL6)) AS LOW_VAL6, LTRIM(RTRIM(HI_VAL6)) AS HI_VAL6  FROM  TBL_CODE WHERE DOM_NBR = ? AND REF_TBL_ID = ? AND EFF_DT <=  ? AND END_DT >= ? AND LOW_VAL1 <= 'ABX' AND HI_VAL1 >= 'ABX' ORDER BY REF_TBL_ID, LOW_VAL1, HI_VAL1, LOW_VAL2, HI_VAL2, LOW_VAL3, HI_VAL3, LOW_VAL4, HI_VAL4, LOW_VAL5, HI_VAL5, LOW_VAL6, HI_VAL6, EFF_DT
```

I am using this sql in jdbcTemplate queryForList and am passing the required number of parameters. This error doesn't happen at all times.

This sql is being run as part of a long running batch job processing application. The application is single threaded. The application code DOES NOT open or close any connections explicitly.

I am using commons Dbcp(version 1.4) for connection pooling and spring JDBC(version 3.2.8)  for data access. I have tried running it with BasicDataSource maxActive = 50 and maxActive=8(default for BasicDataSource) and I receive error in both cases.

In researching this issue I came accross this link from IBM website - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=71&uid=swg21208123

The previous version of the application which used an in-house connection pooling framework and managed its own data access did not throw this exception. I want to make sure that the application code is fine before I request the DBA to create more packages on the server.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This often happens when your application keeps too many open cursors concurrently.

Comment: But I am not actively opening any cursors. All of that is managed by Spring Jdbc for me. is there any way I can control that from the application code?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I used the maxOpenPreparedStatements property of org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource to control the number of open cursors and everything works fine.